# How can I add an event redirecting to a record to a Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, lightning

I have a lightning component, and I want that when I click a div, it redirect me to an object record. I guess I have to use an event but I don't know how it work exactly ? Do you have an example of this use case ?

### Updates

I try, in my component, to add a link, but it doesn't work :

```
<aura:attribute name="actualites" type="Actualite__c[]"/>
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.actualites}">
        <a href="#" data-id="{!a.Id}" onclick="{!c.redirectToSobject}" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{!a.position-1}" class="{!a.classNameIndicateur}"></li>
        </a>
    </aura:iteration>
</ol>
```

with in the js :

```
    redirectToSobject: function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": component.get("v.Actualite__c").Id,
      "slideDevName": "Detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

How cant I create a link on a div ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Dou.. are you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes I do but with an other way for now... I just put a link like that `<a href="{!'https://adress.my.salesforce.com/' + a.Id}">xxxx</a>` but this is not a true solution...

Comment: hmm if you look into the official documentation they mentioned to use navigateTosobject methods etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use `force:navigateToSObject`

**[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm)**

```
redirectToSobject: function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "Detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

> recordId: Required. The record ID.
>
> slideDevName: Specifies the slide within the record view to display
>   initially. Valid options are:
>
> - detail: The record detail slide. This is the default value.
> - chatter: The Chatter slide
> - related: The related information slide

### Updates

Create one more component to redirect to sobject

```
<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.actualites}">
      <c:redirectToSobject objSobject="{!v.a}" /> 
</aura:iteration>
```

### redirectToSobject Component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="objSobject" type="Sobject" required="true" />
    <a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;"> 
        View Record
    </a>
</aura:component>
```

### redirectToSobject Controller

```
({
    navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
         var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
         navEvent.setParams({
              recordId: component.get("v.objSobject").Id,
              slideDevName: "detail"
         });
         navEvent.fire(); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have a question : what are the "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX" and "slideDevName": "Detail" ?

Comment: @dou check my updated ans..

Comment: thank you, for the recordId, can I put a dynamic Id (that I got from an apex controller ) ? Because my component only display the 3 last records and they can change...

Comment: @dou it depends on you. You can use directly dynamic Id or you can get the Id from lightning view using `component.get("v.objSobject").Id`

Comment: so I can write , instead of `"recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX"` , `"recordId": component.get("v.objSobject").Id`

Comment: @dou exactly.. here `objSobject` will be you sobject record

Comment: thank you, I have another question, I edited my question if you are able to help me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38274/discussion-between-sfdcweb-and-dou).

Comment: @dou check this package https://github.com/RatanPaul/Salesforce-Lightning-Dynamic-Datatable I have created you need a separate component for redirecting to sobject

Comment: @dou check my updated ans

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work you may add a tag in your component as below:
`<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>`