# Cannot read property 'navigateToSObject' of undefined in Lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, navigation, sforce

I am developing a Lightning component that lists related Contacts. I would like to make it so that when you click on the name of a related contact, then it will navigate to that contact's record. Here is the component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
     <aura:attribute name="RelatedContact" type="Contact"/>
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
     <ui:outputText value="{!v.RelatedContact.Name}" click="{!goToContact}"/>
 </aura:component>
```

In my controller I have the method `goToContact` as follows

```
goToContact : function(component, event, helper) {
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(component.get("v.RelatedContact.Id"));
}
```

and the method `doInit` as follows

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');  
    script.src = "/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js"; 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.key = "/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js"; 
    script.helper = this;
    script.id = "script_" + component.getGlobalId();
    head.appendChild(script);

    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.src = "/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js"; 
    script2.type = 'text/javascript';
    script2.key = "/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js"; 
    script2.helper = this;
    script2.id = "script2_" + component.getGlobalId();
    head.appendChild(script2);
},
```

Everything appears to load properly, however, when I click on the name a pop up gives me this message

> Something has gone wrong. Cannot read property 'navigateToSObject' of undefined.
>   Please try again.

Comment: no...  use `force:navigateToSObject ` for lightning check docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm  check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117592/18731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fire the event .Lightning is Event driven and different than visualforce .

Use the below event

```
goToContact : function (component, event, helper) {
 var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
   navEvt.setParams({
     "recordId": component.get("v.RelatedContact.Id"),
     "slideDevName": "related"
   });
   navEvt.fire();
}
```

Also to fetch all contacts I would use an AuraEnabled apex class to feed the data to the Front end and not use ajax call as you did .

Comment: I had an issue with the navEvt being null. However, this worked when I added <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/> to the component.

Comment: I am still surprised why you needed to add the dependency here .It makes no sense here

Comment: @LouisPujol thanks for the comment it was null for me as well.. not sure of the reason